# How to show current location in HMS map with custom marker option?

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-map-kit, huawei-location-kit

I have used HMS Map in my app. I am select some location using location kit search and displaying in map with custom marker. I can able to get Latitude and Longitude perfectly. Also i can display the selected location in map too before few days. But currently unable to show. I did not change anything in code. So what should be problem?

```
private fun setMapWithCurrentLoc(lastLocation: android.location.Location?) {
    if (lastLocation != null) {
        val location = LatLng(lastLocation.latitude, lastLocation.longitude)
        if (map != null) {
            map!!.clear()
            map!!.addCircle(
                    CircleOptions()
                            .radius(500.0)
                            .center(location)
                            .clickable(false)
                            .fillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.purple_trans))
                            .strokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.transparent))
                            .strokeWidth(1f)
            )
            map!!.addMarker(
                    MarkerOptions()
                            .position(location)
                            .icon(
                                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(
                                            Utils.createCustomMarker(
                                                    requireContext(),
                                                    childUrl!!
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                            .draggable(true)
            )
            map!!.animateCamera(
                    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude),
                            currentZoomSetting.toFloat()
                    )
            )

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change some of your code and test in a Activity with `com.huawei.hms.maps.SupportMapFragment`, it works okey：

```
override fun onMapReady(paramHuaweiMap: HuaweiMap?) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onMapReady: ")
    hMap = paramHuaweiMap
    hMap!!.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    setMapWithCurrentLoc(LatLng(48.893478, 2.334595))
}

private fun setMapWithCurrentLoc(location: LatLng) {
    var map = hMap
    if (map != null) {
        map!!.clear()
        map!!.addCircle(
            CircleOptions()
                .radius(500.0)
                .center(location)
                .clickable(false)
                .fillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
                .strokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
                .strokeWidth(1f)
        )
        map!!.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions()
                .position(location)
                .icon(
                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher
                    )
                )
                .draggable(true)
        )

        map!!.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude),
                11f
            )
        )
    }
}
```

implementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:6.0.0.301'
could test this in your code to see if works.

Comment: Okay, I will try. Thank you

Comment: Sure,please feel free to contact me if you need any further help. :)

Comment: I used HMS Location Kit Document and solved the issue. Thanks for your Help